# How do I cache a large dataset that takes several minutes to return?

Tags: .net, xml, caching

Here's the background, I have a webservice from a vendor/partner that returns a large XML document that I use to display data. Simple enough. The problem is that the service takes several minutes to execute. The vendor is returning an entire normalized database as an XML document in one method call and it's slow. Stupid vendor but I can't control that.

I have two questions:

1. Where do I cache it? Disk, database, memory (I'm leaning to putting it on disk. It's too big and not accessed enough to store in memory. Putting it in a DB is probably *right* but I don't want to write ETL and have a job running somewhere.)
2. How do I cache it? I can't just let it expire and have the next request refresh the cache because it takes so long. I need to serve stale data while the cache is rebuilding. I can think of a couple of ways of doing it but nothing that seems simple or very elegant. I'm looking to do something simple; I'm not looking for the best engineered solution ever.

Here's my plan...please tell me that I'm an idiot and suggest something easier that I'm overlooking.

    Write the XML to disk
    At the same time write the filename and some type of expiry bomb into cache (obviously the filename would not expire for a very long time)
    In my worker thread, try to read my bomb from cache
    If the cache is expired (my bomb went off) then spawn a thread to get and save the XML
    meanwhile, take the filename from cache and read in the old XML while the new one builds
    when the new one is finished, expire the old filename from cache and write the filename to cache

This sounds pretty much ridiculous to me and there has to be a better way.

I'm using .Net and IIS6 and I can stick the XML in SQL Server if needed.

Comment: Why can't you store those data in memory? How big is the object you want to store?

Comment: Why can't you just up the connection timeout for iis so you have enough time to download the whole file? How big is this file anyway?!

Comment: The object is several MB in size, which I grant you isn't huge but it's also not accessed often enough that I would want to cache it in memory. I have considered just taking the hit and I still might go that direction. I have changed the timeout but I can't have a user waiting 90 seconds for data to render so I need to serve the user something while the cache rebuilds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new database and a scheduled job to periodically fetch those data and store them into the database. Then you can serve the data that are actually needed directly from your database instead of web service.

Comment: I've considered doing this but a SQL job is another point of failure to have to manage and adding another DB is yet another object to maintain. This data was hosted internally up until a year ago. Part of the reason to go with a vendor was to not have to maintain data internally or build the interfaces to manage the data. All we want to do is render the data.

Comment: One other quick thing, if I do stick it in SQL, I'm sticking the entire object in SQL. I'm not going to deconstruct it into its normalized form. This is a project where I have very little time or resources. I have everything finished except for the caching and I don't want to spend time rebuilding my data access layer. I'm not trying to be lazy but rather I'm trying to be pragmatic.

Comment: @Jay, could you please tell us a bit more about that object? You said that object is several MB in size? Do you need to display  the whole object in a view, or you just need to display some part of that object? 90 seconds for data to render is way toooo much.

Comment: Sure, the object is essentially a normalized DB serialized to XML and served up over a web service. The data model would be a master table with several foreign key relationships to other tables some of which have their own foreign key relationships. The level of nesting is maybe 4-5 deep. Frankly, it's not a great web service (not a great vendor). I don't need all the data at once but there's no useful way to extract just what I need. The methods that return subsets of data leave off important fields or require making calls in loops. One example of that is returning a list of contacts.

Comment: Sorry to have to cont...Anyway, I can get a filtered list of contacts but I don't get metadata with the list so I have to make subsequent calls to get the associated metadata for that contact. Honestly, it's a crappy service probably sitting on an improperly designed DB. I'm not sure why the service is so slow to return the base object but it is. Best case is 45 seconds and worst case is almost two minutes. Once I have the object from them and am working with a local copy on disk or in a DB it flies (hence my question about how to cache the thing).